# Does Java naming convension allow `AClassName` with two first capital letters?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I am choosing a name for a class reporting system event messages. Possible names:

(1) `SystemEventMessage` //`SystemEventMessageReportController` gets too long
(2) `EventMessage` //clash with sun.plugin2.message.EventMessage
(3) `Message`   //clash with multiple classes
(4) `EMessage` or `SMessage`  // Preferred way

Is class name like `EMessage` allowed? What would be potential issues with this name?

Comment: Yes it is allowed.

Comment: What's the problem with it clashing?

Comment: You *can* do `EMessage` but doesn't `ErrorMessage` sound better? (just an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it's used (as Victor wrote in his answer) it doesn't mean it's recommended by [Java code convemtions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html):

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of
>   each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple
>   and descriptive. **Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations**
>   (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form,
>   such as URL or HTML).

Comment: In this case, which option should I choose?

Comment: @Stepan option 1 or 2

Answer (score 0):

This is a common way to name . Java Swing has core classes `HBox`, `VBox`, etc.